# RUN FAILED when trying to printf a string from a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

I am learning how to use structures in an attempt to make a card game. I've been messing with this for roughly forever and I cannot get the printf statement to work how I would like. I think it has something to do with `cc2` not being properly assigned to `ctwo.typ` but I'm really at a loss as to what to do about it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char typ[20];
    int num;
} card;

int main(void)
{
    char cc2[] = "Two of Clubs";

    card ctwo;
    ctwo.typ[20] = *cc2;
    ctwo.num = 2;

    //The output of the following is "Two of Clubs"
    printf("%s\n", cc2);

    //The output of the following is "2, "
    printf("%i, %s\n", ctwo.num, ctwo.typ);

    //The output of the following is "2, (null)" 
    printf("%i, %s\n", ctwo.num, ctwo.typ[0]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line: ctwo.typ[20] = *cc2;
is very wrong. Think about that line.

Comment: Yes , thinking ........ that's where you should spend some time rather than trying things out at random. :)

Comment: Too localized was a useful close reason for questions such as this.  It isn't an invalid question, but it doesn't provide any startling insight for anyone else later — it just clutters up searches.  Oh well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C.

You must copy the characters, using the standard library function [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

```
card ctwo;
strcpy(ctwo.typ, "Two of Clubs");
ctwo.num = 2;
```

Since the actual string is constant (a card won't change its name), you can also declare it as a plain `const char *typ;` in the `struct`, and just set the pointer to the string literal:

```
card ctwo;
ctwo.typ = "Two of Clubs";
ctwo.num = 2;
```

This does *not* copy the actual characters, all it does is assign the address of an array of characters which exists "somewhere" in memory to the pointer variable in the `ctwo` structure instance.

Comment: OH MY GOD. I feel so silly. Case closed, bring out the dancing lobsters. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues, you can not assign to an array, you need to use `strcpy`, this:

```
ctwo.typ[20] = *cc2;
```

should be:

```
strcpy( ctwo.typ, cc2 ) ;
```

this `printf`:

```
printf("%i, %s\n", ctwo.num, ctwo.typ[0]);
```

should be:

```
printf("%i, %s\n", ctwo.num, ctwo.typ);
```

`ctwo.typ[0]` is just the first character but you need a `char *`, when you use `%s` [format specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) it is expecting a pointer to a C style string which is a `char` array that is `null` terminated(end with a `\0`). If you want to print a single character you would use the `%c` format specifier and then `ctwo.typ[0]` would be valid.

Comment: Can you explain "you need a `char *`" a bit more? I don't think arrays are pointers.Are they?